# Compute $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/{n \mathbb{Z}}, \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, group-homomorphism

I need to calculate
$$\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/{n \mathbb{Z}}, \  \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$$
but I can't see a way to do it...any hints?

Comment: Hint: Where can $\bar 1 \in \mathbb Z/ n\mathbb Z$ be mapped to ?

Comment: To be more concrete, let $\phi \in \text{Hom}(\mathbb Z / 6\mathbb Z, \mathbb Q/ \mathbb Z)$, and look at $\phi(1)$. One constraint is $6\phi(1) = \phi(6) = \phi(0) = 0$. Are you looking for ring homomorphisms or $\mathbb Z$-module homomorphisms?

Comment: I'm looking for $\mathbb{Z}$-module homomorphisms.

Comment: Then you will see that there are 6 possible $\phi(1)$, each uniquely determines a $\mathbb Z$-module homomorphism.

Comment: Ok...ok I think I've understood, thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Every map $\phi : \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is determined by $\phi(1)$.

We know that $0=\phi(n)=n\phi(1)$. This means that $n\phi(1)$ is an integer, since all the integers are zero in $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. There are therefore $n$ different values for $\phi(1)$:

$\frac{1}{n}, \frac{2}{n}, \dots, \frac{n}{n}=1$

So $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$